# How to determine if a digit divided by 8 is an integer?

Tags: php

How do I determine if a digit divided by 8 is an integer?

for example:

```
32 % 8 = 4, it is an integer.

25 % 8 = 3.125, it is not an integer.
```

I need a working code like:

```
if ($str % 8 == integer){
   // continue working
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `%` operator,  [modulo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), will ALWAYS return an integer - it's the remainder of the division.

If you mean you want to check if a number is evenly divisible by 8, then do

```
if ($str % 8 == 0) {
   ... evenly divisible by 8 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can go with `if (val % 8 == 0)` or with more tricky ways, like `val & 0x0FFF == 0` by using bitwise operators.

Somehow they work in the same way: first snippet checks if the remainder of the division by 8 is zero while second checks if number doesn't have any binary digit for 1, 2, or 4, which would make the number not divisible by 8.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
if(is_int($integer)) {
    // do something with integer
}
```